# How to write the l link function

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

if the $text and the $path is a variable. how to write the l function.
eg: the `$text = $term->name` , the `$path = taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid`
how to write the l function.
i used `l($term->name,taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid`)`. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done everything right, but I think you have missed a `single quote`. Try to copy and paste the following code

```
l($term->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid);
```

Update:

If the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function didn't display the path alias automatically, you can use [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) to get the path alias.

```
l($term->name, drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid));
```

Comment: if i want to invoke the alias path how do i do?

Comment: Updated the answer, kindly recheck.